# Create a copy of a table within the same database with SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I want to create a copy of a table, say **TestTable**, with a new name, say **TestTableNew**, in the same database with the use of an SSIS package. I've created a "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task" for this with the source database specified as both the *SourceDatabase* and the *DestinationDatabase*. When I run this task, the original table **TestTable** is overwritten with a new -empty- **TestTable**.

This might well be something really obvious that I've overlooked, but can I somehow specify another name for the destination table somewhere in this transfer task? Or should I solve this in another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use the "Transfer SQL Server Objects Task" to copy a table to the same database because there isn't an option to specify the new table name. You would be copying table "TestTable" to table "TestTable", which will fail because they both have the same name.

You can set the "DropObjectsFirst" property to true, but that will make you lose your original table and its data, which I think you did on your test, otherwise you would have received a failure message.

The best option here is to use an "Execute SQL Task" to create the structure of your TestTableNew based on your TestTable and then do a simple OleDBSource -> OleDBDestination transformation to load all the data from one table to another.

Comment: I guess you're right. It seems weird though that there would be no way to copy the complete table structure within a specific database with SSIS.

Comment: maybe. If you think about it, how often do you have to copy a table to the same DB other than to testing purposes. Maybe MS didn't consider this as a "ETL process" and didn't implement it. Who know?

Answer (score 0):

My knowledge of SSIS is very limited but I assume you can run sql commands passing in 
parameters and therefore generating something like the following dynamically

```
select *
insert into TestTableNew
from TestTable
```

Comment: That's the idea yes. Advantage of SSIS is that it is easy to copy the index structures as well, that's why I'm not using the ... INSERT INTO ...  sql command.